# Trouble in accessing list element in request scope

Tags: java

I am getting a `NumberFormatException` when I try to access an element of list from a `modelattribute` in the request scope using the below statement

```
"${requestscope. modelattribute. list["+i+"].name}"
```

where `i` can be any number.

But when I directly put a number instead of `i` like

```
"${requestscope. modelattribute. list[0].name}"
```

I get the proper value. Please tell me how to make it work or if there is any other way to do it

Comment: How do you initialize 'i'?

Comment: What does your `NumberFormatException` say? The exception should print out what the value of `i` is that is causing the exception.

Comment: to  averroes i have initialized 'i'  in for loop

Comment: to mdewitt -  it just says java. numberformat. exception : for input string +i+

Comment: Is that your exact code copy and pasted?

Comment: No not the copy, pasted code but i am sure its exactly the same

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code somewhere. The exception says that it thinks the string you are trying to format is "+i+" instead of the value of i. So you probably have an extra quotation mark somewhere, but you don't in the code above. If you add the actual line of code we can see for sure.

Comment: i doubt that's the case but i'll check

Comment: That's what your exception is saying if it says `for input string +i+`

Comment: there's a little problem with the code i gave above, the quote should start before the $

Comment: Can you please edit the question so the code is exactly how it is in the code you are running?

Comment: If you swap `i` with an `int`, example `1`, do you still get a NFE, but with `+1+`?

Comment: i didn't try it but i think it will still give NFE

Comment: If it does, then you have a typo, as I mentioned above in your actual code. If it doesn't give an NFE then you have a typo when you create the i in the for-loop.